# Rotate tweet button text using javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

Hello I have trouble rotating the message on the tweet button..

I tried to insert this script:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://domain.com" data-text="message 1.">Tweet</a>



<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "Message 1";
r_text[1] = "Message 2";
r_text[2] = "Message 3";
r_text[3] = "Message 4";
r_text[4] = "Message 5";
r_text[5] = "Message 6";
r_text[6] = "Message 7";
var i = Math.floor(7*Math.random())

document.write(r_text[i]);

//-->
</script>
```

I inserted this script in the data-text="" but it didn't work.

Comment: What the heck do you do and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to rotate the text you tweet.. using javascript.

Comment: Are you using an additional library to do the tweeting action? This link will redirect to twitter.com/share, but how does this convert to a tweet?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "Message 1";
r_text[1] = "Message 2";
r_text[2] = "Message 3";
r_text[3] = "Message 4";
r_text[4] = "Message 5";
r_text[5] = "Message 6";
r_text[6] = "Message 7";

var title_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("title");
title_tag[0].innerText = r_text[Math.floor(r_text.length*Math.random())];
```

EDITED: Now changes the text within the `<title>` tag, instead of the `<a>`'s `data-text` attribute.

Comment: Doesn't work It just take my <title> tag and set that as message

Comment: I edited my answer. What's there now will change the contents within the `<title>` tag on your page.

Comment: I see but I cant use that since I dont want my title to be changed.. There must be another solution around somehow.

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like this?

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" id="tweet-button" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://domain.com" data-text="message 1.">Tweet</a>



<script language="text/javascript">
var r_text = [
    "Message 1",
    "Message 2",
    "Message 3",
    "Message 4",
    "Message 5",
    "Message 6",
    "Message 7"
];

var tweet_button = document.getElementById('tweet-button');
setInterval(function() {
    tweet_button.innerHTML = r_text[Math.floor(r_text.length*Math.random())];
}, 2000);
</script>
```

You really need to find a tutorial more recent than 1997.